# How can I get rid of "The update information is outdated." warning?

Tags: wingpanel, system, updates

I've been seeing this triangle-shaped indicator:

[image: Update information outdated Indicator]

Telling me the following information:

> "The update information is outdated. This may be caused by network
>   problems or by a repository that is no longer available. Please update
>   manually by selecting 'Show Updated' from the indicator menu, and
>   watching for any failing repositories. "

The Software Updater tells me the system is up-to-date.

As a final note, the indicator seems to go on and off. At first it dissipated without me doing nothing. Then it came back.

Comment: OP, can you edit your post to include a question? At the moment it's not entirely clear what you're asking.

Comment: What is the output when you try `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal?

Comment: Sorry for not forming a question on the first place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using one or more PPAs that don't work might cause this problem sometimes. Run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to check which PPAs are causing the error and remove them if necessary.

Comment: After running the command I saw a conflict with the Spotify Stable PPA. I erased only that one and so far haven't seen the issue appear again.

Comment: For those who use Google Chrome:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome-apt-error-ubuntu

Comment: Hate to resurrect this, but I ran `sudo apt-get update` with no issues raised. Is there another way to manually identify any problem PPAs?